# Changing Locale does not changing Font style

Tags: android, fonts, locale, font-family

I use [this approach](https://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/) to set the locale when the user chooses a new language.

Also I use fonts in styles like this:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">


    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/Font.Default</item>

    </style>
```

And a style for "**EN**" in `values` folder:

```
<style name="Font.Default" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/futuralt</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/futuralt</item>
</style>
```

And another style for another language "ar"(representing Arabic) with **another font** in **`values-ar`** folder:

```
<style name="Font.Default" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/gesstwolight</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/gesstwolight</item>
</style>
```

The problem is when the locale changes, the font representing the locale doesn't being applied **Unless app restarts**. How to Change the font without restarting the app after setting locale?

Answer (score 0):

You could call [recreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) in some place after changing locale.

```
 yourActivity.this.recreate();
```

Comment: I Already tried this.The problem is that Recreating activity does not change the font!